# fitch-style proof C ∨ E , A ∨ M , A → ¬C , ¬S ∧ ¬M ⊢ E

Tags: logic

I want to prove this statement using fitch-style :
C ∨ E, A ∨ M, A → ¬C, ¬S ∧ ¬M ⊢ E

This is what I have at the moment but I'm completely lost on what I should do next or if I've gone down the wrong path. [image]

Any Advice would be appreciated. I have been messing around with it for pretty much the whole day but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried proof by contradiction? It's obvious assuming ¬E then from your premises  it must be C, then by MT it implies ¬A, then implies M, which contradicts the last PR. *Speak of the false is to reveal the true* as hinted by Shurangama sutra long ago...

Comment: It goes like this. (1) A v M, A -> ~C yields ~C v M. (2) ~S ^ ~M yields ~M. (3) ~M and ~C v M yields ~C. (4) ~C and C v E yields E. Translate that into your chosen system.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close!

Since "C v E" holds, you want to show that not C. Hint: start with disjunction elimnation on "A v M". You have already shown that A implies E. So you need only show that M implies E to finish.

Comment: Can you show me how? I still can't seem to get it. Though I do understand what you are saying